# Accessing google spreedsheet through api

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access google spreadsheet, however when I make the request I keep getting an error even though the sheet is set public and published.

> The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request

[the spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V1EHtEuBeAhUaW6Ei8v8OnWP11FrWKtBhGQYDbadsCU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you enable the Sheets API in your Google Developer Console. And when making this request, make sure you use valid API key with it. This error is usually caused by incorrect or missed some configuration in Authorizing Requests. If you [authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing), make sure you use the proper scope with it.

For more information, you can check this [thread](https://ikaisays.com/2013/07/19/debugging-your-google-oauth-2-0-token-when-you-get-http-401s-or-403s/) on how to debug your Google OAuth 2.0 token when you get HTTP 401s or 403s